# Mysql Mode On Linux CentOS

Tags: mysql

I installed Mysql 5.6 On CentOS Linux 
By Default it Set SQl Mode Strict

```
 SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |

 SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode                         |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I changed sql_mode via command line from root User to none via command

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

After this i executed commands above commands and they showed

```
 SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode |
+--------------------+
|                    |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+-------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode |
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**But when i restarted Mysql Server i again set Strict Mode i.e**

```
 SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |

 SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode                         |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

**I also added mysql-mode="" in my.cnf file but result was same after restarting mysql**

Comment: @tombom I do not get what is the problem ... maybe he wants to use the default mode : "The modes value also can be empty (--sql-mode="" on the command line, or sql-mode="" in my.cnf on Unix systems" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't know about that.

Comment: @tombom no worries mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem & here is what I worked:

edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf

and add the following

```
[mysqld] 

sql-mode=""
```

you can also check out the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 3):

Add in your my.cnf file :

```
sql_mode = ""
```

Then restart mysql

Here is what it should look like :

```
user        = nobody
port        = 3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
open_files_limit = 50k
sql_mode = ""
```

Comment: i did but again when i restart Mysql Server sql_mode Changed to strict

Comment: @Engr.UmairAzizAttari strange ... i tested it on local and it works fine. Are you sure in your my.cnf file there is only one line where `sql_mode` is set ? maybe it gets overwritten

Comment: or maybe you have a cron that sets the variable globally to strict ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in Centos, you need to follow these steps:

1. Login to root
2. Clieck on SQL services then select MySQL Configuration
3. It will open the configuration file
4. At the end of that file add below:
   sql_mode=""    (not sql-mode="")
5. Go back to Dashboard and try to restart MySQL Database Server available at the right bottom side.
6. If there is any error in config file, it will throw an error, go back and fix the error accordingly.

If you want to test this in command mode use this like:
service mysqld restart

and make sure that it is showing OK in green letters.